# рамка вокруг ссылки с фоном

Tags: html, css

Вокруг ссылки образуется белая рамка. Как избавиться от этого эффекта?

```
.social a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
height: 23px;
width: 23px;
margin: 0;
background: url('../img/main-sprite.png') no-repeat center;}
```

[image: рамка]

Comment: очень подробно рассказал, показал шикарный пример. Ты бы лучше скрин присобачил

Comment: Добавил скриншот

Answer (score 1):

Приоритетный вариант - с использованием `svg`, как и было написано выше. Однако если их нет, можно обойтись и png-изображениями. Здесь, насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что изображения в спрайте некачественно вырезаны.

Answer (score 0):

ну для начала можно было дать `border-radius:50%;` ссылке, а вот вторых используй `svg`  спрайты, а не `png`. И в спрайт засовывать нужно не с фоном (синий, красный...), а иконку и каждой ссылке давать свой цвет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить свойство

```
outline:none; 
border:none;
```